# Change root user's home directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: directory, root

Title says it all, how do I change the home directory of the 'root' user in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the instructions, but be sure to know what you're doing.

On every *nix system you'll find a file called `/etc/passwd` which lists all users and some settings. Here is the syntax of that file:

`username:password:uid:gid:additional_info:home:shell`

So, for example, you'll find:

`root:x:0:0::/root:/bin/bash`

Which means the user is called root, the password is hidden (it's on `/etc/shadow`), uid is `0`, gid is `0`, no additional info, the home directory is `/root` and the default shell is `/bin/bash`.

Edit that file (I recommend `vipw` to avoid corruption) and change the home directory.

However, I don't see any reason to do it.

Comment: You should probably use the `vipw` command to edit the `passwd` file. It sets locks to avoid file corruption. Messing up `/etc/passwd` can easily hose your system.

Comment: Thanks that will work. Just for general information, I need to change the home directory for a VPS template - it's just an ease of use thing

Comment: @user1710563: It might be helpful to update your question to explain why you need to do this. The general reaction (mine included) has been "Don't do that"; if you tell us why you want to do this, you're likely to get better information -- including possible alternatives that don't require changing root's home directory.