# When I create a file on the desktop,it create in /root/desktop not /home/desktop

Tags: root

When I create a file on the desktop,it create in `/root/desktop` not `/home/desktop`,how can I fix it?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/209858/change-root-users-home-directory-in-ubuntu "how can I fix it" you consider that a problem? If you want a Linux with a root user you should stop using Ubuntu. Ubuntu is intended as a "sudo" system and is built with that in mind. Yes, it can work with root but you would not be the 1st to kill your system due to files changing ownership to user "root" where it should be a user owning them.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I think you read the question backwards.  He says the files *are* going to /root instead of his own home directory, not that he *wants* them to.

Comment: Are you logging in as root for some reason?  If so, don't do that.

Comment: @psusi sorry but that can only happen when you use root as a login. It is not possible as a normal user (it would either require sudo OR a it is a really messed up ownership to /root).

Comment: @Rinzwind, I agree.. that's why I asked if he was logging in as root.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged as a normal user, say, `chris`, your desktop will be at `/home/chris/Desktop`, not `/home/desktop`. If you're logged in as `root` (which should be impossible to do with a normal Ubuntu installation), your desktop will be at `/root/Desktop`.